# Rename ggplot x-axis labels using a named vector containing subscripted characters

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I'd like to replace the x-axis labels in my plot with a named vector. Some of the new names have characters I'd like subscripted. I've given an example below in which I'd like "H2O2 500 µM" to be "H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> 500 µM".

I've read this can be done by enclosing replacement text in `expression()`, but this doesn't seem to work when using a named vector to replace names.

Here's a simplified demo.

```
demo_data <- structure(list(treatment_duration_weeks = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15), treatment = c("negative_control", "negative_control", 
"negative_control", "treatment1", "treatment1", "treatment1", 
"treatment2", "treatment2", "treatment2", "treatment3", "treatment3", 
"treatment3", "treatment4", "treatment4", "treatment4", "H2O2-500uM", 
"H2O2-500uM", "H2O2-500uM", "negative_control", "negative_control", 
"treatment1", "treatment1", "treatment2", "treatment2", "treatment3", 
"treatment3", "treatment4", "treatment4", "H2O2-500uM", "H2O2-500uM"
), level = c(100, 100, 100, 107, 148, 126, 112, 160, 131, 112, 
159, 122, 113, 170, 130, 54, 64, 24, 101, 100, 105, 190, 96, 
170, 84, 176, 98, 171, 53, 59)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


treatment_rename <- c("negative_control" = "NC",
                      "treatment1" = "Treatment 1",
                      "treatment2" = "Treatment 2",
                      "treatment3" = "Treatment 3",
                      "treatment4" = "Treatment 4",
                      "H2O2-500uM" = "H2O2 500 µM")

ggplot(demo_data, aes(x = treatment, y = level)) +
  facet_wrap(~ treatment_duration_weeks) +
  stat_summary(aes(fill = treatment),
               fun = mean, colour = "black", geom = "bar") +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill = treatment),
              shape = 21, colour = "black", 
              width = 0.1, height = 0, 
              size = 3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,  
               geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = treatment_rename) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

I've tried posts like this, but can't get it working.

[How to subscript the x axis tick label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978011/how-to-subscript-the-x-axis-tick-label)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `scales::label_parse()`which of course still requires to create a vector of proper math expressions:

```
library(ggplot2)

treatment_rename <- c(
  "negative_control" = "NC",
  "treatment1" = "Treatment~1",
  "treatment2" = "Treatment~2",
  "treatment3" = "Treatment~3",
  "treatment4" = "Treatment~4",
  "H2O2-500uM" = "H[2]*O[2]~500~µM"
)

ggplot(demo_data, aes(x = treatment, y = level)) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment_duration_weeks) +
  stat_summary(aes(fill = treatment),
    fun = mean, colour = "black", geom = "bar"
  ) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill = treatment),
    shape = 21, colour = "black",
    width = 0.1, height = 0,
    size = 3
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = mean_se,
    geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = \(x) scales::label_parse()(treatment_rename[x])) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

[image]

A second option would be to use unicode subscripts:

```
treatment_rename <- c(
  "negative_control" = "NC",
  "treatment1" = "Treatment 1",
  "treatment2" = "Treatment 2",
  "treatment3" = "Treatment 3",
  "treatment4" = "Treatment 4",
  "H2O2-500uM" = "H\u2082O\u2082 500 µM"
)

ggplot(demo_data, aes(x = treatment, y = level)) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment_duration_weeks) +
  stat_summary(aes(fill = treatment),
               fun = mean, colour = "black", geom = "bar"
  ) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill = treatment),
              shape = 21, colour = "black",
              width = 0.1, height = 0,
              size = 3
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = mean_se,
    geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = treatment_rename) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

[image]